# Can't delete sysmis spss variables

Tags: variables, spss

Need to delete spss variable without the data (sysmis data)

The command IF(SYSMIS(V1)) DELETE VARIABLES V1. doesnt' work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_if.htm?lang=en) command does not work in this way, that you are attempting. It operates on a case by case basis i.e. so **IF** a case matches a certain criteria **THEN** apply a certain transformation to **THAT CASE ONLY** (not a variable as a whole).

If you do not dynamically need to search for empty variables (which is possible with python - see below) then all you need is the [`DELETE VARIABLES`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_delete_variables.htm?lang=en) command (or alternatively [`ADD FILES`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_add_files_overview.htm?lang=en) or [`MATCH FILES`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_match_files_overview.htm?lang=en) command all achieving exactly the same result - with the exception of `DELETE VARIABLES` requiring no pending transformations so in which case I personally prefer `ADD FILES` or `MATCH FILES`).

Any one of these 3 commands should suffice:

```
DELETE VARIABLES v1.
ADD FILES FILE=* /DROP=v1.
MATCH FILES FILE=* /DROP=v1.
```

If however, you need to dynamically check if a variable is empty and then only delete it, then you can use python to do so.

You will need to have python integration installed and correctly setup for your version of SPSS and [`spssaux2`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app#/file/108ce263-b14e-4375-9f70-6d1f733d132b) module downloaded and saved in the appropriate location where SPSS can find it, for the below to work:

```
DATA LIST FREE / A B C D.
BEGIN DATA 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
END DATA. 
COMPUTE C=$SYSMIS.
DATASET NAME DSSIM.

BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spssaux2
spssaux2.FindEmptyVars(delete=True)
END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 0):

SYSMIS doesn't refers to variables but cells. From your approach you have to ;

COUNT(SYSMIS(V1)) and if its equal to your case(row on data file) count then you can DELETE VARIABLES V1.